# dateFromString with iOs 4.3

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, ios4

I have a trouble with the iOs 4.3 GM seed. When I launch this code :

```
// Set the dates
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"y G"]; 
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"3000 av. J.-C."];
```

It's giving me this error :
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString substringFromIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'
 error.

This wasn't the case with iOS 4.2. Do you know where it is coming from ?
(I can use @"3000 BC"format, it is working, but I'd like to understand where does this crash comes from)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer : I have to choose the locale system of the date formatter and keep only one date format.

```
NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
```

Before the system was accepting "3000 av. J.-C." and "3000 BC" notation without setting the locale system, now it's not. I guess Apple want us to specify the date format to avoid guessing it.